# Discontinuity of Transition Matrix in Homogeneous Markov Chain with Continuous Time

Tags: continuity, markov-chains

Can the transition matrix of a homogeneous Markov chain with continuous time be discontinuous with respect to t?

Comment: Hint: is the exponential function continuous?